# How many ways can you create a password of 10 characters long that has at least one lowercase letter (a-z) and at least one number ($0-9$)?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, faq

Suppose you want to generate a password using ASCII  characters ($128$ characters.)How many ways can you create a password of 10 characters long that has at least one lowercase letter (a-z) and at least one number ($0-9$)?

** MY ANSWER: $26*10*(128)^{10}$**

I don't understand why this is wrong? Can anybody help? Thanks!

Comment: Your answer is the amount of passwords you could generate that starts with a lower case letter, followed by a number, followed by 10 other ASCII characters. So, it's a string of length 12, and you don't take into consideration the different permutations.

Comment: ASCII characters 0 through 31 are control characters, so for practicality you would never use these in a password. Same goes for 127, the delete character. And character 32 is the space character, which is questionable in a password. So if this is not just an exercise, you might want to limit your available characters to 94 0r 95.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to count all the passwords, then deduct those that don't meet the requirement.  There are $128^{10}$ total passwords, ignoring the requirement for a lower case letter and a number.  Of those $(128-26)^{10}$ have no lower case letter and $(128-10)^{10}$ have no number.  But we have deducted twice those that have no lower case letter and no digit-an example of the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  So we add them back in-there are $(128-36)^{10}$ of those.  So the final answer is $128^{10}-102^{10}-118^{10}+92^{10}=578747468760442009600$ per [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=128%5E10-102%5E10-118%5E10%2b92%5E10)$

Comment: Is the power of 12 correct?

Comment: @Amzoti:  No, I was fixing it while you looked.

Answer (score 1):

It is easiest to concentrate first on the **bad** strings, the ones that do not qualify. These are the strings that are missing a lower-case letter, or a number, or both.

There are $102^{10}$ strings with no lower-case letters, and $118^{10}$ with no numbers. However, if we add these two numbers we are double-counting the words that miss both letter and number. There are $92^{10}$ of these. It follows that there are $102^{10}+118^{10}-92^{10}$ bad strings. Thus the number of good strings is
$$128^{10}-102^{10}-118^{10}+92^{10}.$$