# Calculate password combination with password policy

Tags: combinations

Assume user must choose 8 character password using:

1. lowercase letters a-z (size=26)
2. uppercase letters A-Z (size=26)
3. digits 0-9 (size=10)
4. special characters/symbols (size=33)

policy 1) user can choose password freely

my answer:  $95^8$ combinations, since 26+26+10+33 = 95.

policy 2) 
The password must at least have one digit or at least one special character.

my answer: number of passwords with at least one digit = $10^8$

number of passwords with at least one special character = $33^8$

number of passwords with at least one digit **or** at least one special character equals to $10^8$ + $33^8$

are my calculations correct or I am making some stupid mistake?

Comment: $26^8 + 26^8 + 10^8 + 33^8 \ne  95^8$

Comment: @miracle173 - of course, I expressed my thoughts wrong on 'paper', corrected.

Comment: @miracle173: $(26+26+10+33)^8=95^8$!!!

Comment: Could we reach the same answer by "constructing" a valid password for policy 2? That is, picking any "digit or special" (33+10), then placing it in a position in the password (8 possibilities), then picking all the other characters ($95^7$ possibilities)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many ways can you create a password of 10 characters long that has at least one lowercase letter (a-z) and at least one number ($0-9$)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260446/how-many-ways-can-you-create-a-password-of-10-characters-long-that-has-at-least)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your second part, number of valid passwords will be the total number possible minus the invalid ones.

Total number = $(26+26+10+33)^8 = 95^8 $

Invalid ones are those which contain neither a digit nor special character.
Thus available characters are only upper and lower case alphabets.
Invalid = $(26+26)^8 = 52^8 $

Thus acceptable passwords are: $95^8 - 52^8$

Answer (score 1):

$10^8$ is the number of passwords composed of only digits, not the number with at least one digit.  The number with at least one digit is $95^8-85^8$ as we subtract all those composed of non-digits.  Can you extend this?

Comment: yep, understood

Answer (score 0):

**You've made several mistakes:**

---

Number of passwords with at least one digit is $10^8$.

No, it is $(26+26+10+33)^8-(26+26+33)^8$, or simply $95^8-85^8$.

---

Number of passwords with at least one special character is $33^8$.

No, it is $(26+26+10+33)^8-(26+26+10)^8$, or simply $95^8-62^8$.

---

Number of passwords with at least one digit or one special character is $10^8+33^8$.

No, it is $(26+26+10+33)^8-(26+26)^8$, or simply $95^8-52^8$.