# Password Combination Problem

Tags: combinations

A user must choose $ n $ characters password using:

1. uppercase letters $ A-Z (size=26)$
2. lowercase letters $ a-z (size=26)$
3. digits $ 0-9 (size=10)$

Each password must contain at least an uppercase and a digit.

What should be the formula to calculate number of valid passwords of size $ n $, give $ n >= 1$ ?

I have calculated it to be:

Uppercase x Digit x combination of all 3 types = $ 26\times10\times(26\times26 \times10)^{n}$

Comment: Hint: How many passwords of size 1 are there? What does your formula say?

Comment: hmm it should be 0 but the formula gives a rather large number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many ways can you create a password of 10 characters long that has at least one lowercase letter (a-z) and at least one number ($0-9$)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260446/how-many-ways-can-you-create-a-password-of-10-characters-long-that-has-at-least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably inclusion-exclusion. There are $62^n$ strings of length $n$ using the characters provided. There are $36^n$ such strings without an uppercase letter, and $52^n$ such strings without a lowercase letter, and $26^n$ such strings without either.

Thus, the total number of valid passwords of length $n$ is
$$
62^n - 36^n - 52^n + 26^n,
$$
where you add the number of strings without either back in, because you have subtracted it twice.

Comment: why is the case for without upper case 36^n? Do I have to remove the strings without lowercase since an its not required for a password to contain any lowercase characters?

Comment: There are 36 characters which are not uppercase letters: 26 lowercase letters and 10 digits.

Answer (score 1):

The answer should be calculated as all possible combinations $(26+26+10)^n$, minus the incorrect ones (no uppercase, no digits).

Because of inclusion/exclusion, you have to ADD (you subtracted twice) all solutions that have no uppercase and no digits (all lowercase).